# Skip sql-maven-plugin execution from command line

Tags: java, maven, sql-maven-plugin

How can I prevent `sql-maven-plugin` from executing when doing `mvn clean install` from the command line? I cannot touch the pom file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`sql-maven-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/index.html) does provide a [`skip`](http://www.mojohaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/execute-mojo.html#skip) property but there is no corresponding user property.

If you can't modify the POM file, there are 2 scenarios:

1. The plugin is configured like this:

   ```xml
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.5</version>
     <!-- dependencies and executions blocks omitted for brevity -->
     <configuration>
       <skip>${someProperty}</skip>
     </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```

   In this case, you can run `mvn clean install -DsomeProperty=true` to skip the execution of the plugin.
2. The plugin is not configured like above. In this case, you're out of luck and you will not be able to skip the execution. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/mojohaus/sql-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/sql/SqlExecMojo.java#L226), there is no user property for the `skip` property. Your only move would be to make an enhancement request to implement this at [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/mojohaus/sql-maven-plugin). You could also provide a pull request: it seems the only change would be to add a `property` attribute to the `@Parameter` annotation.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that to be the case.