# Disable a maven plugin from command line

Tags: java, maven

I have a mock java class, by default I would like to exclude it from the `mvn install command`.
But when I'm working on my local machine I would like to include it in my .war launching by command line something like: `mvn clean install -DsomeProperty=true`

I added this plugin to my profile:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/filter/MockFilter.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                        <skip>${someProperty}</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

But the class is always skipped. How can I include it? I give a try to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009902/skip-sql-maven-plugin-execution-from-command-line) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836978/maven-skip-compile), but nothing worked.

Comment: Did you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166895/different-dependencies-for-different-build-profiles I think it could help you

Comment: And what if you get rid of the <skip> and you add an <include> and based on your propertie you include or exlude your MockFilter.java?

Comment: @T.K by default with mvn install I would like to exclude MockFilter.java

Comment: the profile is a solution, but I already have 2 different profiles, and in this way I have to duplicate a very long profile to add to the new profile only this plugin, it looks too verbose.

Comment: Maybe this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430122/how-to-define-conditional-properties-in-maven but I'm not sure if what you ask is really possible